# Get web service from api Twitter 1.1?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've registered my application at Twitter as depicted below

[image]

I'm trying to fetch a `JSON` file of tweets with a specific hashtag like "#dog". However, I'm having authentication problems. I'm using Javascript.

http://jsfiddle.net/rgapegw3/

```
 /*
 consumer_key=I_HAVE
 &consumer_secret=I_HAVE
 &user_token=I_HAVE-I_HAVE
 &user_secret=I_HAVE 
*/

$.getJSON("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%23colombia&result_type=recent",

function (data) {
    alert("IT WORKED!");
},function(data){
    console.log("problem")
});
```

Comment: classic, you redacted everything BUT the secret

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17143985/twitter-api-error-215

Comment: @LawrenceCherone what do you say?

Comment: you cant use version 1.1 of the api as it requires oauth authentication, you will need to proxy the call through server side code which can handle the oauth..

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I'll look at the tutorial you passed me. thank you very much. But I believed that everything could be done in a simple web request.

Comment: np, for the most part it can, check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17084201/jquery-tweet-js-plugin-is-not-working-how-to-show-tweets/17084479#17084479 for a simple proxy, which can be adapted for your needs

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I get confused a bit. I need to do the web service specifically from angular.js or jquery. But I'm not using php or backend. Only from front-end

Comment: do some research its not possible or advised with just javascript, unless you implement the complete oauth process (see the php code), you would also need to pass your twitter app private keys to the client, not good.. its the standard with oauth apis is to have a backend.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone In conclusion if or if, I should use php in my case.

Comment: For a simple proxy, you could use the one in the link, or if you want something more advanced/official use there libs https://dev.twitter.com/resources/twitter-libraries

Comment: This is a good one: https://twitteroauth.com/