# embed twitter hashtag feed in a web page

Tags: html, twitter, feed, hashtag

I want to embed a twitter hastag feed in my web page, as a widget ( like the attached picture )
can any one help?

[image]

Answer (score -5):

You could use https://publish.twitter.com/# to create the code for you.

Just fill in the link and then continue along the process. Once it gives you the embed code such as

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/shibaeveryday?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">Tweets by shibaeveryday</a> <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Just paste it wherever you need to.

Comment: This does not work for searches (hashtags), unfortunately.

Comment: Please be very specific in your request. Noone but you knows exactly what you want. I believe then you are going to be trying to access the twitter api. There are tons of these tutorials everywhere.

Comment: I already tried it but It give just a button on wich we can click to tweet , what I need is all  tweets with a specific hastag

Comment: did you find any solution for it?

Comment: @PooyaPanahandeh I posted the answer

Comment: @RoyChan - as far as being very specific in the OP's request: This is precisely why it's best to ask for clarifications, as comments, on the original question, and not post an answer to a very broad, unclear question.

Comment: @Namoat found any solution?

Comment: @Namoat where did you post the answer?!

Comment: I found this solution in an other post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57463772/11377513) . 

You can use the Javascript library "TweetJS", from www.tweetjs.com

You can retrieve and display tweets(only from last 7 days) using this library, but you cannot post out tweets, since this requires authentication. Here's an example:

https://www.tweetjs.com/Search.html

Comment: Like everyone is saying, this is not a solution to the request for hashtags.